# Pattern matching digits does not work in egrep?

Tags: regex, grep, character-class

Why can't I match the string

```
"1234567-1234567890"
```

with the given regular expression

```
\d{7}-\d{10}
```

with `egrep` from the shell like this:

```
egrep \d{7}-\d{10} file
```

?

Comment: I just tried /\d{7}-\d{10}/ and it works fine with that string.

Comment: It doesn't work; I've written that string from above inside file - but nothing ?!

Comment: @persistent: maybe you need to whip up a hex editor and see what those digit characters really are.

Comment: Hey :D ; just a simple digits forwarded from the standard output with
echo; echo string > file

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`egrep` doesn't recognize `\d` shorthand for digit character class, so you need to use e.g. `[0-9]`.

Moreover, while it's not absolutely necessary in this case, it's good habit to quote the regex to prevent misinterpretation by the shell. Thus, something like this should work:

```
egrep '[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{10}' file
```

#### See also

- [`egrep` mini tutorial](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~tal/3261/fall07/handout/egrep_mini-tutorial.htm)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

  - [Flavor note for GNU `grep`, `ed`, `sed`, `egrep`, `awk`, `emacs`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html)

    - Lists the differences between `grep` vs `egrep` vs other regex flavors

Comment: Actually he only needs to quote the regex if it contains shell meta-characters. And now that it no longer contains backslashes, it doesn't, so quoting is optional.

Comment: @sepp2k: do you need quote for a space? I think you do. I guess you can argue that a space is a shell metacharacter. Anyway I think it's best to always quote, ala it's best to always use curly braces.

Comment: Then how would be with grep instead; I'm interested in \d prefix?!

Comment: @persistent: according to comparison chart I linked, neither POSIX ERE (egrep) nor POSIX BRE (grep) knows `\d`, `\s`, `\w`, `\b`, etc. Also `\d` is not a prefix; it's a shorthand for the digit character class supported by many but not all flavors.

Comment: Well that's odd; then where they're specified if not inside (e)grep ?

Comment: It's not prefix; inside the sintax it must be specified as a prefix before the  brackets; thx for the correction anyway ;)

Comment: @persistent: different flavors of regex does things differently, that's why it's important to mention which flavor you're using when asking regex questions, etc. I'll guess that Perl popularized the `\d` shorthand, and everyone else followed later.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Yes, you need quotes with spaces (or put a backslash before every space). And sure, it doesn't hurt to always quote.

Comment: @persistent: you can't use `\d` with grep/egrep; you can use its expanded form `[0-9]` which is practically the same thing, but slightly longer. In some flavors that supports Unicode, `\d` is not the same as `[0-9]` because it also includes some other Unicode digit characters.

Comment: Well mate; I already knew for the [block]{} form ; I was interested in \d; thx

Comment: I don't ever use `[0-9]`, when I really mean `[[:digit:]]`. Plus these character classes are supported almost everywhere, and are defined in POSIX.

Comment: '\d' wasn't working for me, but '\s' and '\w' did today. grep (GNU grep) 2.23 Packaged by Homebrew.

Answer (score 27):

For completeness:

Egrep does in fact have support for character classes. The classes are:

- [:alnum:]
- [:alpha:]
- [:cntrl:]
- [:digit:]
- [:graph:]
- [:lower:]
- [:print:]
- [:punct:]
- [:space:]
- [:upper:]
- [:xdigit:]

Example (note the double brackets):

```
egrep '[[:digit:]]{7}-[[:digit:]]{10}' file
```

Comment: Just a complaint about grep: `[[:digit:]]` is worse than `[[0-9]]` in every possible way. None of these are  short hand, and they are harder to rememer than the default regex syntax. EG: `[[:lower:]]` is harder to remember, read and write than `[a-z]`

Comment: @Zombies But `grep -E` i.e. `egrep` supports both `[:digit:]` and `[0-9]` so where is the complaint? If you're comparing with `\d` it's arguable. d could stand for anything, a bit like one letter variable names. Still seems \d has become more popular. I think grep character classes pre-date Perl `\d`

Answer (score 22):

you can use `\d` if you pass grep the "perl regex" option, ex:

`grep -P "\d{9}"`

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: Not in FreeBSD. Option -P is not supported, unfortunately.

Comment: If you're running AWS CodeBuild you'll still have this issue and you'll need to use `grep -P`

Answer (score 11):

Use [0-9] instead of \d. egrep doesn't know \d.

Comment: According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html, repetition in `grep` is `\{7\}`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Sure, I thought he was asking about \d.

Answer (score -3):

try this one:

```
egrep '(\d{7}-\d{10})' file
```

Comment: Traditional egrep did not support the { metacharacter, and some egrep implementations support \{ instead, so portable scripts should avoid { in egrep patterns and should use [{] to match a literal {.

Comment: However neither traditional egrep nor GNU egrep support \d and that's why this does not work - not because of the {. Though it'd be useful to keep the { thing in mind if you ever have to be compatible with traditional egrep.